# Get Min value of each group in a table based on another col

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have table (Cost for a Product by location and month/date) in the format below and want to get Min of ChangeDate for whenever Cost has changed.

```
Cost            Loc     Prod        ChangeDate
--------------------------------------------------------
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-01-03 00:00:00
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-01-31 00:00:00
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-02-28 00:00:00
1.000000000000  5678    12345678    2010-04-04 00:00:00
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-05-02 00:00:00
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-05-30 00:00:00
1.223000000000  5678    12345678    2010-07-04 00:00:00
1.277200000000  5678    12345678    2010-08-01 00:00:00
1.277200000000  5678    12345678    2010-08-29 00:00:00
1.277200000000  5678    12345678    2010-10-03 00:00:00
```

Expected output is:

```
Cost           Loc  Prod     CostChangeStartDate
------------------------------------------------
1.223000000000 5678 12345678 2010-01-03 00:00:00
1.000000000000 5678 12345678 2010-04-04 00:00:00
1.223000000000 5678 12345678 2010-05-02 00:00:00
1.277200000000 5678 12345678 2010-08-01 00:00:00
```

I tried using Row_Number() Over(PartitionBy OrderBy) but the problem is 
since Cost 1.223000000000 is repeated twice, I am unable to partition it properly so getting only 3 records.

Comment: `select cost, loc, prod, min(changeDate)
from your_table
group by cost, loc, prod`

Comment: @juergend that would only get the *first* time the cost hits each value. E.g. It hits 1.223 twice in the data above.

Comment: @MANDROID, do you really want the `1.223` value to be `2010-01-03` on both rows?

Comment: for versions of sql server prior to 2012, you can use a difference in row numbers (e.g. `row_number() over (order by x) - row_number() over (partition by cost order by x)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rows that have a different cost to their previous row using [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx):

```
select * from (
    select *, lag(cost, 1) over (partition by Loc, Prod order by ChangeDate) prevCost
    from @products
) x
where prevCost is null or cost <> prevCost
```